# Good algorithm to turn stl map into sorted list of the keys based on a numeric value

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stl, dictionary, c++03

I have a stl map that's of type:

```
map<Object*, baseObject*>
```

where

```
class baseObject{
    int ID;
    //other stuff
};
```

If I wanted to return a list of objects (std::list< Object* >), what's the best way to sort it in order of the baseObject.ID's?

Am I just stuck looking through for every number or something? I'd prefer not to change the map to a boost map, although I wouldn't be necessarily against doing something that's self contained within a return function like

```
GetObjectList(std::list<Object*> &objects)
{
   //sort the map into the list
}
```

Edit: maybe I should iterate through and copy the obj->baseobj into a map of baseobj.ID->obj ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for `std::list`? Sorting `std::vector` can be more efficient since the sort algorithm can rely on random-access iterators that are not available in list.

Comment: Not really, but that's not the main issue. The list/vector is of the keys, not the values, so I'd need to get that somehow.

Comment: So you want to sort the *keys* according to a property of the *value*? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: yep. I think maybe just creating a new map of value->keys would work, unless there's a more efficient way.

Comment: @Jordan: you don't actually say, but presumably the id's are unique (not two `Object*` keys are mapped to equal `baseObject*` pointers, or to different pointers whose referands have the same value of `ID`)? If not, then you can't contemplate creating a map of baseObject.ID -> Object*.

Comment: They are unique, actually. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is first extract the keys (since you only want to return those) into a vector, and then sort that:

```
std::vector<baseObject*> out;
std::transform(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::back_inserter(out), [](std::pair<Object*, baseObject*> p) { return p.first; });
std::sort(out.begin(), out.end(), [&myMap](baseObject* lhs, baseObject* rhs) { return myMap[lhs].componentID < myMap[rhs].componentID; });
```

If your compiler doesn't support lambdas, just rewrite them as free functions or function objects. I just used lambdas for conciseness.

For performance, I'd probably `reserve` enough room in the vector initially, instead of letting it gradually expand.

(Also note that I haven't tested the code, so it might need a little bit of fiddling)

Also, I don't know what this map is supposed to represent, but holding a map where both key and value types are pointers *really* sets my "bad C++" sense tingling. It smells of manual memory management and muddled (or nonexistent) ownership semantics.

You mentioned getting the output in a `list`, but a `vector` is almost certainly a better performing option, so I used that. The only situation where a `list` is preferable is really when you have no intention of ever iterating over it, and if you need the guarantee that pointers and iterators stay valid after modification of the list.

Comment: great LINQ-like approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll do fine with:

```
GetObjectList(std::list<Object*> &objects)
{
  std::vector <Object*> vec;
  vec.reserve(map.size());
  for(auto it = map.begin(), it_end = map.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
    vec.push_back(it->second);
  std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](Object* a, Object* b) { return a->ID < b->ID; });
  objects.assign(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

Comment: I'm using VS2008, can't use lambda's, unfortunately.

Comment: Better return the list by value, rather than take by reference and then clear, reserve and so on.

Comment: `std::sort` requires a random access range.  `std::list` only provides bidirectional iteration.  If you really need `std::list`, you'll need to use its `sort` member function.

Comment: Also note that the `id` is not a property of the `Object` but of `baseObject` (I find the names in the question confusing, but I can only assume that `Object` does not have an `id` field.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that I would not use a `std::list`, but rather a `std::vector`. Now as of the particular problem you need to perform two operations: generate the container, sort it by whatever your criteria is.

```
// Extract the data:
std::vector<Object*> v;
v.reserve( m.size() );
std::transform( m.begin(), m.end(), 
                std::back_inserter(v),
                []( const map<Object*, baseObject*>::value_type& v ) {
                     return v.first;
                } );
// Order according to the values in the map
std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), 
           [&m]( Object* lhs, Object* rhs ) {
               return m[lhs]->id < m[rhs]->id;
           } );
```

Without C++11 you will need to create functors instead of the lambdas, and if you insist in returning a `std::list` then you should use `std::list<>::sort( Comparator )`. Note that this is probably inefficient. If performance is an issue (after you get this working and you profile and know that this is actually a bottleneck) you might want to consider using an intermediate `map<int,Object*>`:

```
std::map<int,Object*> mm;
for ( auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it )
   mm[ it->second->id ] = it->first;
}
std::vector<Object*> v;
v.reserve( mm.size() );                  // mm might have less elements than m!
std::transform( mm.begin(), mm.end(), 
                std::back_inserter(v),
                []( const map<int, Object*>::value_type& v ) {
                     return v.second;
                } );
```

Again, this might be faster or slower than the original version... profile.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do what you said, "sort it in order of the baseObject.ID's":

```
typedef std::map<Object*, baseObject*> MapType;
MapType mymap; // don't care how this is populated
               // except that it must not contain null baseObject* values.

struct CompareByMappedId {
    const MapType &map;
    CompareByMappedId(const MapType &map) : map(map) {}
    bool operator()(Object *lhs, Object *rhs) {
        return map.find(lhs)->second->ID < map.find(rhs)->second->ID;
    }
};

void GetObjectList(std::list<Object*> &objects) {
    assert(objects.empty()); // pre-condition, or could clear it
    // or for that matter return a list by value instead.

    // copy keys into list
    for (MapType::const_iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it) {
        objects.push_back(it->first);
    }
    // sort the list
    objects.sort(CompareByMappedId(mymap));
}
```

This isn't desperately efficient: it does more looking up in the map than is strictly necessary, and manipulating list nodes in `std::list::sort` is likely a little slower than `std::sort` would be at manipulating a random-access container of pointers. But then, `std::list` itself isn't very efficient for most purposes, so you expect it to be expensive to set one up.

If you need to optimize, you could create a vector of pairs of `(int, Object*)`, so that you only have to iterate over the map once, no need to look things up. Sort the pairs, then put the second element of each pair into the list. That may be a premature optimization, but it's an effective trick in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new map that had a sort criterion that used the component id of your objects.  Populate the second map from the first map (just iterate through or std::copy in).  Then you can read this map in order using the iterators.

This has a slight overhead in terms of insertion over using a vector or list (log(n) time instead of constant time), but it avoids the need to sort after you've created the vector or list which is nice.

Also, you'll be able to add more elements to it later in your program and it will maintain its order without need of a resort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to store in your map but perhaps [look here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

The third template argument of an std::map is a less functor. Perhaps you can utilize this to sort the data stored in the map on insertion. Then it would be a straight forward loop on a map iterator to populate a list